# How to set HorizontalAlignment of TabControl in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to set the `HorizontalAlignment` property of a WPF `TabControl` in the code-behind file (not in XAML), but there doesn't seem to be any way to do it.  Is there a way to set this property in code without creating a style for the entire control?

Comment: Post some code to understand more about your issue.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that Visual Studio was referencing `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` instead of `System.Windows.Controls.TabControl`.  The WPF version has a `HorizontalAlignment` property, whereas the Winforms version does not. 
Forcing it to create a `System.Windows.Controls.TabControl` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to name your TabControl, then you will be able to reference it in code behind.  Like this:

```
 <TabControl Name="MyTabControl" />



this.MyTabControl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```